# How do I return another line between each object?

Tags: powershell, join, formatting, newline, operator-keyword

I am trying to return an extra line between each line of the output for my code.
I have tried using the -join "`n" operator in different places in the function, but it never seems to work.

I'm unsure as to where exactly I should put it.

It currently returns like this:

```
Name: Testie Mctest
UserPrincipalName: testie.mctest@test.com
etc.
etc.
```

Though i'd like it to look like this:

```
Name: Testie Mctest

UserPrincipalName: testie.mctest@test.com

etc.

etc.
```

I'm sure there's an easy solution to this, i'm just new to PowerShell.
Thanks in advance.

```
function Get-ADUserInfo
{
    param
    (
        [Parameter (mandatory = $true, Position = 0, ValueFromPipeline = $true)]
        [ValidateLength (3, 10)]
        [String]$Username
    )

    #create an array for a neater script
    $ADUserproperties =
    @(
        "Name"
        "UserPrincipalName"
        "Description"
        "Enabled"
        "CanonicalName"
        "Created"
        "pager"
        "LockedOut"
        "PasswordExpired"
        "PasswordLastSet"
        "BadLogonCount"
        "badPwdCount"
        "LastBadPasswordAttempt"
        "LastLogonDate"
    )

    try
    {
        Get-ADUser -Identity $Username -Properties $ADUserproperties | select $ADUserproperties

        Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership -Identity $Username | select-object Name -ExpandProperty Name | Sort-Object -Descending | Out-GridView -Title "$($Username)'s AD Groups:"

    }

    catch
    {
        "Could not find '$($Username)' in Active Directory"
    }
}
```

Comment: I see you called the function `get-aduser` in your `get-aduserinfo` function but I don't see it anywhere in your code. Did you define it somewhere?

Comment: It's a built in command to the ActiveDirectory module in Powershell

Comment: I see, thank you for informing me

Comment: `...  | select $ADUserproperties | Foreach-Object {$_; ''}`

Comment: Or `(Get-ADUser -Identity $Username -Properties $ADUserproperties | Select-Object $ADUserproperties | Format-List | Out-String) -replace '\r?\n', "\`r\`n\`r\`n"`

Comment: @iRon, the foreach loop didn't seem to work.

Comment: @Theo thanks for that. That worked.

Might I ask though, with **-replace '\r?\n', "`r`n`r`n"** 
what is the question mark for after the first "r"?

Comment: @beezkneez the `\r?` means there is either one or zero CR characters before the LF. Windows uses CRLF (Ascii 13 + Ascii 10) for a newline. *Nix only does LF. `\r?\n` will catch both.